# Clear text inside DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the following HTML structure:

```
<div id="clock">5:30 AM
    <div id="day">Wednesday
    </div>
    <div id="date">14 December
    </div>
</div>
```

I update the contents of these elements using Javascript. For "day" and "date" I use `$("#day").text(day)` and `$("#date").text(date)`. Because "clock" is a parent element I had to use `$("#clock").prepend(clock)` to succesfully add the text.

The problem with the latter function, is that new text is prepended every time the clock is refreshed, i.e. it builds up a list of clock times. For the first two functions the text is just replaced, like it should. Is there a way to make this happen for the "clock" function as well?

EDIT: Sorry, should have been a bit more clear about the clock. Have edited the code, so you understand. BTW, the reason the clock is parent element is that could make the other two elements depend on the clock's position and styling.

I also created a jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/daanodinot/NZtFA/
I left the list building thing (annoyingly) in!

BTW, I'm not too sure if `function(); setInterval('function()', 1000)` is the best way to refresh, so if you something better I'd be happy to know :)

Comment: you're using jquery don't you ?

Comment: Could we see your JS code please?

Comment: what exactly is `clock` that is being prepended?  Could you put a demo together on http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: what is your `clock` variable?

Comment: I've created a project on jsfiddle.net so you can try it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is change the structure of your html to this.

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="clock"></div>
    <div id="day"></div>
    <div id="date"></div>
</div>
```

Then for the javascript

```
$('#clock').text('12:45'); 
$('#day').text('Wednesday'); 
$('#date').text('12/14/2011');
```

This way you can just change/refresh the text of clock instead of prepending values to it.

Another approach, with your current html, which i do not recommend.

```
<div id="clock">
    <div id="day">
    </div>
    <div id="date">
    </div>
</div>
```

The js

```
$('#clock').contents().get(0).nodeValue = '12:45'; 
$('#day').text('Wednesday'); 
$('#date').text('12/14/2011');
```

Comment: Thanks, glad you understood the question :) Will update the my post so it becomes a bit more clear. The second approach you mention seems to be about as good as it gets with my current html structure. I think you're right that I better have the "clock" element as a child element as well. The reason that I chose it as parent element was that I could make the day/date position and styling depend on the clock, but that can be solved easily with a seperate wrapper of course.

Answer (score 1):

If you have HTML

```
<div id="clock">
  <div id="day"></div>
  <div id="date"></div>
</div>
```

Then you don't have to modify `#clock` at all. By doing `$("#day").text(day)` and `$("#date").text(date)` content of those divs is changed and you don't have to touch `#clock`.

But in case you want to replace a content of a element then use `.html(newContent)`. See [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html2).

Comment: Clock is the current time, which i'm guessing he's refreshing. If he does do a `$('#clock').html(..)` then he would replace `day` and `date` which is probably not intended.

Comment: @Interstellar_Coder He was not clear what `#clock` is (or am I blind? :/ ), so I was just guessing in the answer. I'm not suggesting to use `.html()` in case clock is time, of course. I just showed how to replace content of the elemenet *IF* he needs it :).

Comment: dz fair enough, more details would have been better.

Answer (score 0):

You should first add a new element with prepend and then replace it's content, now you just constantly keep prepending new elements instead of working on the same element again.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by

> Because "clock" is a parent element I had to use
>   $("#clock").prepend(clock) to succesfully add the text.
>   ?

It seems redundant. Since $('#day') and $('#date') uniquely address your targeted elements.

My tip:

Do not use `clock`. `$("#day").text(day)` and `$("#date").text(date)` already update the numbers inside your #clock element.

Answer (score 0):

Hy,
my consideration for your problem is, IF you choose to manipulate the Content of the #clock div you could simply do this:

```
var newContent="";//in here comes whatever you want to add to your clock div
$('#clock').html($('#clock').html()+newContent);
```

That's the way I use it most of the time but you could also do this:

```
var curContent=$('#clock').html();
curContent+="<>put in your code to add</>";
$('#clock').html(curContent);
```

This is I guess a bit slower than the first one, but it works.

Comment: He wants to refresh the contents of all three divs, not append old content to new one.